# How to size color background

Tags: php, css, colors, background

I want give size to color of below code, means I can give size image background, but I want also give size to this background color `#e5e5e1` how I can do it?

```
background:url("masjedol-aghsa-small.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #e5e5e1; opacity: 0.9;
```

its my `php/html` code:

```
<div class="spacetitlebox faseleyebala col-sm-6">
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('box1') ) : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: .... what? You want to re-size... color?

Comment: sorry i edit it, i want give size to color

Comment: post your html too.Sounds its too easy

Comment: its my php/html code: <div class="spacetitlebox faseleyebala col-sm-6">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('box1') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I really understand what you mean, but ..
I think you should use a "div" markup, which contains your image background, and you give to the div the size you want.

Try this :

```
<div class="spacetitlebox faseleyebala col-sm-6">
    <div style="background-color :#e5e5e1">
        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('box1') ) : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Totaly agree with your answer

Comment: Tks @GillesBodart. I hope this is what he wants.

Comment: i want size background color, where is size of background color exactly?

Comment: just here : <div style="background-color :#e5e5e1">

Comment: can you please change size for background color for me at this code: <div style="background-color :#e5e5e1">

Comment: @antoniojosedemaiasantos what must we do ??